# Analysing skewed, bounded data using beta regression models?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, model, beta-regression

I'm trying to analyse the outcome of a biology experiment with a troublesome response variable. The response is left skewed and appears to be bimodal, has a lower theoretical limit of zero, and has an approximate upper limit too (the response is the size of the biggest egg inside an insect in mm - so, eggs can't have negative size, and in practical terms they do not get bigger than a couple of mm before being laid).

I don't know of a good "family" to deal with this type of data using common generalized linear models, so I was looking into beta regression. One could express the size of the egg in each insect as a proportion of the size of a large, fully grown egg (which we can assume is about the same as the biggest egg observed in the experiment). As I understand it, beta regression can handle bimodality in the data and it works with data on the scale of 0 to 1.

My question: is beta regression the right tool here? And if so, is the R code below correct given the structure of my experiment, which includes a fixed effect and two random effects? I was puzzled that one cannot specify beta in the "family" argument in hglm, and I'm not sure if the model is doing what I want at present.

Thanks!

```
library(truncnorm)
library(hglm)

# Make some fake data that resembles mine
fake.data <- data.frame(y = rbinom(400, 1, 0.75),  
                    treatment = rep(rep(c("A", "B"), each=4),50), 
                    rand1 = rep(1:100, each = 8), 
                    rand2 = rep(1:4, each = 100))

# Roll random numbers to make the bimodal, continuous response variable. I chose values such that the distribution looks pretty much like my own data.
fake.data$y[fake.data$y==0] <- rtruncnorm(sum(fake.data$y==0), mean = 1, a=0)
fake.data$y[fake.data$y==1] <- rtruncnorm(sum(fake.data$y==1), mean = 4, a=0, b=5)
hist(fake.data$y) # Have a look at it

# First idea: Express the response as a proportion of the biggest value in the data, and then use beta regression
# Is this model specification correct, and am I using the right model?
# The aim of my experiment is to determine the effect of treatment, and ideally also to get some least-squared means for each treatment group after accounting for the "noise" from the random effects

fake.data$y <- fake.data$y / max(fake.data$y)
summary(hglm2(y ~ treatment + (1|rand1) + (1|rand2), data= fake.data, rand.family= Beta()))
```